# My Android Fragment code returns IllegalStateException, but only some times

Tags: android

Occasionally IllegalStateException occurs in BottomNavigationView.
It's difficult to reproduce because it rarely happens.
Where is the mistake at my code?

Error always

```
fm.beginTransaction (). hide (active) .show (fragment1) .commit ();
```

It happens here

```
Fragment active = fragment1;

navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem)
    {
        switch (menuItem.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.timer:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();    // Error location
                active = fragment1;
                break;

            case R.id.favorite:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().detach(fragment2).attach(fragment2).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().show(fragment2).commit();

                active = fragment2;
                break;

            case R.id.calendar:
                fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().detach(fragment3).attach(fragment3).commit();
                fm.beginTransaction().show(fragment3).commit();

                active = fragment3;

                break;
        }
        return true;

    }
});
```

Comment: If the Error is not because of BottomNavigationView then change the title

Comment: @MathaN It's corrected